# Prove (n choose k) ((n − k) choose (m − k)) = (n choose m) (m choose k)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let k, m, and n be integers with 0 ≤ k ≤ m ≤ n, and let S be a set of size n.
Prove that

(n choose k) ((n − k) choose (m − k)) = (n choose m) (m choose k)

by counting, in two different ways, the number of ordered pairs (A, B) with A ⊆ S, B ⊆ S, A ⊆ B, |A| = k, and |B| = m.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to start will be highly appreciated

Comment: First you should learn to Latex.

Comment: @user275740 Try wrapping \binom{a}{b} and _aC_b in $\$$ symbols to get $$\binom{a}{b} \quad \text{and} \quad _aC_b$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.

- For the LHS, first choose the elements of $A$; then choose more elements for $B$ to make up the required number.
- For the RHS, first choose the elements of $B$, then from these elements, choose the elements of $A$.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your kind input working on it :)